# Union of selects within a loop with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
--------------------
| color |   date   |
--------------------
| red   | 01/01/10 |
| blue  | 01/07/10 |
| ...              |
```

I want to select the maximum date of every type. The easy way has (realy) bad performance. ie:

```
   SELECT color, MAX(date) 
     FROM myTable
    WHERE color = ANY(ARRAY('red', 'blue'))
 GROUP BY date;
```

What has good performance the following query. I think this is because of the index on date.

```
    SELECT color, date
      FROM myTable
     WHERE color='red'
  ORDER BY date
     LIMIT 1
```

the problem is that I do not have the same result. I would like to find a way to use the 2nd version to have the same result as the first query.

Perhaps I could use a Loop and select the union of each result. Is this even possible?

Any other idea is welcomed?

Comment: What do your indexes look like?  You need the aggregate to get the same effect

Comment: Also, `IN(ARRAY('red', 'blue')` has multiple serious problem, please update your question to include your real queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need the array keyword?  Doesn't this do what you want for the first query?

```
SELECT date, MAX(color) 
FROM myTable
WHERE color IN ('red', 'blue')
GROUP BY date;
```

But you seem to want:

```
select color, max(date)
from mytable
group by color;
```